# Modal creating class object and setting values

Tags: ios, swift, oop

Hello this problem is more concerned with the programming problem rather then the specific language syntax. I am getting a nil `user_id` value after setting a value in class object. So I thing I am doing something wrong here

I have two classes. **User** and **Trip**

**Trip.swift**

```
class Trip: NSObject {


    var tripID: Int?
    var tripTitle: String?
    var user:User?


    var params: [String:NSObject] {
        return [
            "user_id": self.user!.userID!,
            "trip_title": self.tripTitle!,
        ]
    }
```

When I send these `params` to server I get a nil value user_id

```
 var trip: Trip?
 trip?.user?.userID = 9
```

I am not writing a whole code. I think I am doing something wrong in modal class or not setting the userID correctly. Please let me know if you can't figure out the problem from this info so I'll post full code here

```
class User: NSObject {

    var userID: Int?
    var email: String?
    var password: String?
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?



    var params: [String:NSObject] {
        return [
            "email": self.email!,
            "password": self.password!,
            "first_name": self.firstName!,
            "last_name": self.lastName!,



        ]
    }
```

Comment: Show us the User class.

Comment: Have you set `trip` to an instance of `Trip`?  Is `trip.user` a `User`?  You haven't shown enough information or code

Comment: @EarlGrey I have updated my question

Comment: No i didn't set any instance. @Paulw11

Comment: Basically this is all the work I am doing for setting and getting values. The only code which I am missing is how I am sending the paramters to server

Comment: Then how can you assign a value to the userID property if there is no user and there is no trip?

Answer (score 1):

If all the data in both classes is always mandatory in real life, then

1. you should **not designate** those properties as optional.
2. This will force you to write **proper initialisers** and then
3. you will be **forced** to populate each object with **correct values**, which in turn
4. will lead to **abandoning** the need for **force-unwrapping** just before you send to server.

Following these steps will fix your problem.

**Bonus advice:** You don't have to inherit from NSObject. Do not inherit from anything. Everything here is possible to do with swift standard library. The dictionary then will use AnyObject as value.